# Remove a DOM element using JavaScript so I can reuse ID elsewhere in single page web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, garbage-collection

I have currently got a single page web app that uses jQuery with XML to dynamically generate panels and elements of a form inside a DIV in the page. Once the form is complete and response sent to server a new xml form and data is sent to the app which has to render the new page. All goes well except if the user session ends and they login again and the new xml for the form is received. On being returned to the login panel the form DIV is cleared by using the following jQuery;

```
$('#scriptForm').children().remove();
```

This removes the elements from the DOM but when the new items are loaded the previous elements are still present.

How do I force the DOM to discard the initial child elements without reloading the full page from scratch?

Comment: That should work in principle. Must be bugs elsewhere. Post some code.

Comment: Try this alternative    $('#scriptForm').html("");

Comment: Seems an eronuous error stopped it working. Fine now